# How to run OpenNMT-py model to translate a given string in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, opennmt

The documentation only mentions using the command line to run the `translate.py` script already given in the `OpenNMT-py` repo, i.e. use

`python translate.py -model model_name.pt -src data/src-test.txt -output pred.txt`

and that's fine, but how do I use the `onmt` library to load the trained model in a jupyter notebook and make translations on the go? I want it to be able to do something like this in jupyter:

```py
model = onmt.module.load(/path/to/model.pt)
text = "hola como estas"
model.translate(text)

Output:
>>>Hello how are you
```

I can't find any documentation on how to do this. Please help!

Comment: you should probably look within the `python translate.py` file on how they do

Comment: You might want to create a REST translation server. OpenNMT forum has a detailed tutorial: http://forum.opennmt.net/t/simple-opennmt-py-rest-server/1392]